# One wiki question for "How to learn instrument X?" book recommendations?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have an idea for a Community Wiki question, but I'd like to feel-out the room before unilaterally creating it.

We get a lot of questions requesting resources, which are each individually off-topic; ***BUT*** what if they were all neatly confined to a single page, community-editable, each answer outlining a curriculum for a specific instrument or music topic? An *annotated bibliography* for the site?

So, it would look something like this:

---

## Music Practice & Performance Community Wiki Resource Guide for Learning Music

The page is intended to contain a collection of answers, each targeted to a specific musical instrument which should offer a list of books or other resources that would be useful in studying that instrument.

Eg.

## Guitar

### Classical Method and Technique

- Romero, Celedonio. (out of print)
  Some explanation of the contents.
- Segovia, Andres, etc.
  Some explanation of the contents.

### Rock Technique

- Something else.
  Explanation of contents.

### Easy Songbooks

- *Rise up Singing!*
  A collection of lyrics and chord-changes of popular and folk songs collected from *Sing out!* magazine.

If you have more books or resources for a topic that already exists as an answer, please edit the existing answer to add the new resources, rather than create a new answer which will make the information more difficult to find.

Comment: This seems like it could get awfully large and unwieldy.

Comment: I feel like we should start with a smaller subset, like music theory, and see how it turns out.  If it turns out good we can extend it to other subsets like guitar, bass, piano, ect.

Comment: That does seem wise to start small. I can start it off with a "share-your-knowledge" q+a, about theory books, but I need to get back my pile from my cousin first. :)

Answer (score 2):

While there are some notable resources that stand the test of time, I think the concern is that this would require frequent updating so loses it's value as a Q&A resource rapidly.

Comment: I think you and @Matthew raise valid concerns, but ... I don't sense a strong verdict. The size could be assisted by adding an index of the answers to the question. ... That unfortunately would exacerbate the frequent-updating problem. ... Hmmm ....

Comment: Yeah - I'm definitely not against it in principle, but the Stack Exchange argument against this general category of questions does make sense.