# Are software recommendations on topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/45274/what-tool-could-i-use-to-generate-songs-from-text) in a different SE site, and I guess it could be asked here too.

The question goes like this:

> Is there a tool that can be used to generate songs (only de human
>   voice) from a text file in a similar way to how [speech
>   synthesizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis#Text-to-speech_systems)
>   do?
>
> Such tool should be able to separate the words into syllables, using
>   some meta notation, and also support intervals of silence, beside
>   allowing to specify the pitch and duration of each note.

[Here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8l6rTJRQrI&feature=youtu.be&t=1m7s) of how the output might sound like.

Comment: See also https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/878/28